# How to use math in controller variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I simply need to be able to use math to set the end point of a query in my controller.

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController   
  def index
    @video = Video.last
    @videos = Video.last(7).reverse!.drop(1)
  end

  def show
    @video = Video.find(params[:id])
    @videos = Video.where(:id => start..stop)
  end
end
```

This line: `@videos = Video.where(:id => start..stop)` should be something like `@videos = Video.where(:id => params[:id]..params[:id]-7)` because that array is supposed to be the next seven database entries after `@video`.

I'm also certain there's a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do but I have no idea what it is.

Comment: This is a common issue, and most people solve it using a pagination gem like [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate).

Comment: The `params[key]` always returns a string (or `nil` if the key does not exist). To perform arithmetic operations, you have to explicitly call `to_i`.

Comment: @Aetherus code example of this?

Comment: `Video.where(:id => params[:id].to_i..params[:id].to_i-7)`

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is using a gem called **will_paginate**, which will automatically do what you are trying to solve

Example would be

```
 @videos = Video.paginate(page: params[:page] || 1, per_page: 5)
```

you can get the page from the params, so your web page has to request something like this `/videos?page=2`

Other gem in this category is `Kaminari`

Comment: I really can't figure out how pagination it supposed to help me accomplish what I'm trying to do. I need the second variable to be an array of the next 7 database entries past the link the user clicked on, which is this one `Video.find(params[:id])`. Although pagination will be useful to me later on in another area of the application I don't see how it's applicable here.